# Error "document.getElememtById is not a function" al intentar referenciar al valor de un elemento

Tags: javascript

No me sale el resultado.

```js
function celsius() {
    var f = document.getElememtById("fahrenheit").value;
    var c = (f - 32) * 5 / 9;
    alert("La Temperatura: " + f + " Expresada en Celsius es: " + c);
}
```

```html
<p>
  <input type="text" id="fahrenheit" size="9" maxlength="12"/>
  <input name="celsius" type="button" onclick="celsius()" value="Convertir fahrenheit a celsius"/>
</p>
```

Comment: cual es el error que te sale??

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el resultado esperado? Realmente "No obtengo un resultado" es una descripción muy vaga del problema... Por otro lado, ¿no es bastante claro el error que aparece en consola?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tienes un error en tu código. Debería de ser

```
document.getElementById
                 ^
```

en vez de:

```
document.getElememtById
                 ^
```

Tu código modificado:

```js
function celsius() {
    var f = document.getElementById("fahrenheit").value;
    var c = (f - 32) * 5 / 9;
    alert("La Temperatura: " + f + " Expresada en Celsius es: " + c);
}
```

```css
body{
  background-color: #666666;
}
```

```html
<p><input type="text" id="fahrenheit" size="9" maxlength="12"/><input name="celsius" type="button" onclick="celsius()" value="Convertir fahrenheit a celsius"/></p>
```

Comment: @aldanux ¡¡Por fin un voto negativo con un comentario constructivo sobre él!! Te lo agradezco de verdad. Sinceramente, ni pensé en que no era adecuada al sitio, tenía mono de responder preguntas y respondí tres o cuatro seguidas. Para la próxima vez ya estaré más atento para cerrarla en vez de contestarla, aunque lo que me resulta más gracioso es que esta es la que recibió más votos positivos de todas las que contesté y es la menos elaborada de todas.

Comment: @aldanux Sí, si realmente no suelo contestar a este tipo de preguntas y las cierro directamente aunque hay veces que me pillan con las defensas bajas y acabo contestando xD

Answer (score 0):

Has esto, cambialo en tu código:

```
var f = document.getElementById("fahrenheit").value * 1;
```